# CKeditor security issue--does it impact CiviCRM and what to do?

Tags: ckeditor, security

Drupal security reported
Project:
Drupal core
Date:
2021-May-26
Security risk:
Moderately critical 14∕25 AC:Basic/A:User/CI:Some/II:Some/E:Proof/TD:Default
Vulnerability:
Cross Site Scripting
Description:
Drupal core uses the third-party CKEditor library. This library has an error in parsing HTML that could lead to an XSS attack. CKEditor 4.16.1 and later include the fix.

What should CiviCRM uses do regarding CKeditor within CiviCRM? Is the library installed or is it served via CDN and updated to the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20428 which will be in 5.38. But my quick read of it is that the addons affected are not installed by default.